# Assignment inside condition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In the MATLAB programming language is it possible to have, just as in C/C++/etc., an assignment inside an `if` or `while` condition? For example:

```
if (a = 1)
    % Always true in this particular example
end
```

This generates the error: `Invalid syntax at '=' Possibly a ), }, or ] is missing`.

If this is not natively supported, is there any practical workaround?

**EDIT:**
Obviously the example above is dummy code to keep the question simple and understandable without unnecessarily complicating the code and is not actually intended for deployment (see the comments).

Comment: or indeed just `a = 1;`

Presumably this is a dummy example and the true intended use is more complex, but seriously there is never a good reason to use this idiom in Matlab (or even in C, really -- most C compilers will warn about it because it's so error prone).

Comment: @hbaderts For the same reason you do it in C? Of course, the right-hand side would not just be `1`. For example: `if a = (b==c)`. You do the comparison and assign it to a variable, all in the same statement

Comment: @LuisMendo Would you do that in C? I already came across something like `if(x=doSth())` but I see no advantage over `x=doSth(); if(x) `. Is there any?

Comment: @hbaderts Not that I know of, except shorter code (if that's an advantage).

Comment: @walkytalky Yes, it is dummy code and I do not agree with you, in some situations there are obvious 'benefits' from 'inline' assignment. As for example consider a memory allocation in C with `malloc()`. You can assign and check for errors in one go using such an inline assignment. I've never see a compiler complain about this construction. Not even with `-Wall`. I updated my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Also another use is to make use of the short circuit evaluation on some programming languages to prevent array out of bound conditions while keeping a compact and readable code.

Comment: @hbaderts On second thought, I may have misunderstood this question...

Comment: @LuisMendo No problem. I should have made it more explicitly that the example was not intended for actual deployment. You are free to answer the question :)

Comment: This is typically used for error management in C. MATLAB has [try-catch](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html), so no need for this insane construct, which would often lead to hard to track bugs, just because of a missing `=` due to a typo.

Comment: @knedlsepp So it is not possible in MATLAB? If not (or if it can) please add it as an answer. Please note that this question is not about if such construct is good practice, but about if MATLAB supports it in any shape or form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: **No.**

---

Assignment in Matlab doesn't return a value, so no, it is not possible in a sensible way. Moreover, arguments are passed by value, so you can't just fudge it with a function that does the assignment and returns a value.

If you were willing to wrap your assigned variable up in a custom Handle object and pass it to a function then you could maybe do something sort of approximating what you want, but it would be very ugly and require more additional steps than just writing the code the straightforward way. It certainly wouldn't give you the benefits you seem to think this idiom provides.

Comment: Thank-you. This is all what I was looking for, but for some reason people try to downvote and close the question. I'm not sure why everybody looks so down onto this idiom, it is very often used in C, even in things like the Linux kernel and gcc, so why not in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get you right, but if you just want an if statemant or a while loop, you need

`if a == 1
b = 1;
end`

if you want an always true, make something like

`while true
b = 1;
end`

Comment: Please see the updated question and discussion above. This currently does not address the issue.